# User input to linux command in C

Tags: c, linux

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>

void getCommand(char* cmd, char** arg_list)
{
pid_t child_pid;

child_pid = fork();

if (child_pid == 0)
{
    execvp (cmd, arg_list);
    fprintf(stderr, "error");
    abort();
}

}

int main(void)
{

printf("Type the command\n");

char *arg_list[] = {NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL};

char cmd[20];
char delim[2] = " ";
char *token;

scanf("%[^\n]", cmd);

token = strtok(cmd, delim);

while (token != NULL)
{
    arg_list[0] = token;
    token = strtok(NULL, cmd);
}

getCommand (arg_list[0], arg_list);
return 0;
}
```

What I'm trying to achieve here is I want to read user input, which should be a linux command, and then execute the command. It seems that I can't use strtok to split my string. I'm kinda lost, thanks for the help.

Comment: paddy got your main problem.  You should get in the habit of checking errno.  Printing "error" isn't going to tell you much.  Also you might want to have the parent `wait` on the child.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your successive calls to `strtok` are wrong.  You need to pass the delimiters.  Also, you are only writing to the first element of your array.  Try this:

```
int n = 0;
while (token != NULL && n < 7)
{
    arg_list[n++] = token;
    token = strtok(NULL, delim);
}
```